# Delphi DOM Xml appendChild in for statements

Tags: xml, delphi, dom

AHello I am currently working on a project that allows interaction between xml files and DataSet.

Here is my code:

```
    // Number of lines of the DataSet = Number of "REC" element
    for i := 0 to aDataSet.RecordCount - 1 do
    begin
      // Create a new Node
      aNewNode := aXml.createElement('REC');

      for j := 0 to slColumnName.Count - 1 do
      begin
        aNewNode.setAttribute('x','y');
      end;

      // Add new Node
      aNodeTBL.appendChild(aNewNode);
    end;
```

aNodeTBL -> Corresponds to the parent node, I want to create as many nodes "REC" that lines my DataSet.

I can see that I'm still on the "aNewNode", so juste one "REC" node is written

Should I re-instantiate "aNewNode" ?

Comment: You already are, when you call `createElement()`.  So what is the ACTUAL problem you are having?

Comment: I'm sorry, i saw my error, i forgot to read through ma DataSet.Poor I am...Do you know if i can add a carriage return when i do the createElement ?

Comment: This code builds a tree of nodes. You should not be worrying about whitespace and line breaks when building a tree, only when converting the tree to a string when you are done building it. (T|I)`XMLDocument` has an `doNodeAutoIndent` flag for inserting whitespace/linebreak elements into the resulting XML. Or look at the `FormatXMLData()` function.

Comment: I'm worry because the xml file has to be compare in TFS with the previous version. Or if the new xml file is not AutoIndent, it will be difficult to compare easily :). I take a look at FormatXMLData. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `aNodeTBL.AddChild()` instead of `aXml.createElement()` and `aNodeTBL.appendChild()`:

```
// Number of lines of the DataSet = Number of "REC" element
for i := 0 to aDataSet.RecordCount - 1 do
begin
  // Create a new Node
  aNewNode := aNodeTBL.AddChild('REC');

  for j := 0 to slColumnName.Count - 1 do
  begin
    aNewNode.Attributes['x'] := 'y';
  end;
end;
```